# I am Dutch citizien (EU) married to a US citizen. Can I travel to US to visit my husband during travel ban?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, esta, covid-19, netherlands

I have a valid ESTA and my husband lives in the U.S. and my immigration visa is in processing.

Comment: Which one are you? A Dutch person with an American husband or an American person with a Dutch wife?

Comment: I am Dutch my husband is American. I know he can come to visit due to a change in travel restriction for couples. But don't know if I can visit him under the same circumstance.